# Extjs combobox is not auto-selecting the displayField

Tags: extjs, combobox

**UPDATE -**
I HAVE ALSO MADE A MOCK IN JSFIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/mAgfU/371/
AND WITH A FORM PANEL : http://jsfiddle.net/kA6mD/2/

I have the bellow comboox.
When I use the following code to set the form values:

```
this.form.loadRecord(data);
```

the entire form is acting ok except from the combo.
instead of giving me the `displayField`, I get the `valueField` in the display.

[image]

As you can see in the image above, the combo should show the word "Walla" (`displayField`) instead of "1" (`valueField`)

```
  Ext.define('App.view.ForeignCombo', {
            extend: 'Ext.form.ComboBox',
            alias: 'widget.foreigncombo',
            queryMode: 'local',
            displayField: 'Name',
            valueField: 'Id',
            editable: false,
            matchFieldWidth: false,
            constructor: function(config) {
                Ext.apply(this, config);
                Ext.define('BrnadComboModel', {
                    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
                    fields: ['Id', 'Name']
                });
                this.store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                    model: 'BrnadComboModel',
                    autoLoad: true,
                    proxy: {
                        type: 'ajax',
                        url: '/api/Brand/',
                        reader: {
                            type: 'json',
                            root: 'Results'
                        }
                    },
                    pageSize: 50,
                });
                this.callParent();
            }
        }
    );
```

this is how I use it:

```
{
  "xtype": 'foreigncombo'
, "name": 'Brand.Id'
, "fieldLabel": 'Brand.Id'
}
```

**There is no race bewtween the form display and the combo ajax request, the combo store is autoLoad:true, meaning I see that it has already been loaded...**

Thanks

Comment: I didn't really get the last comment (the bold font one) but did you put a breakpoint right before the view loads and checked whether the store has data loaded in it? I've had this problem before and it mostly was because the store was not done loading when the window showed up... not saying this is the case though (yet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used your fiddle a an example. Place a breakpoint in line 87 (Ext.ComponentQuery.query('comobobox')....), in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kA6mD/9/, and set a watch to Ext.ComponentQuery.query('combobox')[0].store.data.. you'll notice the store has no data. This may be linked to what I mentioned in the comment.

I know there must be a better way of doing this, but what I usually use as a workaround is either load the store at some point before in the app or use a synchronous Ext.Ajax.request and load each record at a time in the store.

As this is a combo for brands I suppose you could load the store before (i.e. app load) and lookup for the store instead of creating a new one each time you create a foreigncombo component, so the first solution should work.

As for the second workaround it should also work, it takes a little bit more coding but its actually pretty easy. It should look something like this...

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url:'your/url/',
    async:false,
    .....
    success:function(response){
        var records = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
        for(var m=0; m<records.length; m++){
            var record = Ext.create('YourBrandModel',{
                abbr:records[m].abbr,
                name:records[m].name
            });
            store.add(record);
        }
    }
})
```

You should do this as few times as possible as it may slow down the user experience if it gets called everytime you create a "foreigncombo", so checking if this store exists before creating one might be a good idea.

Please take in cosideration that I have not tested this code, so you may have to tweak it a little in order for it to work. But it should get you on tracks.